# Azure API Management - How to execute product policy when product does not require subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a product published that does not requires a subscription. The 4 APIs that compose it also does not. How can I define policies on a product level?
Such policies seem to work only when both the APIs **AND** the product require subscription **AND** the request is made using the product subscription key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prerequisites:

1. API subscription switched off:

[image]

2. Product subscription switched off:

[image]

3. Product added to API:

[image]

4. Product has policies defined, example:
   [image]

If above points are true, just call your API **without** Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header and APIM will automatically execute API and attached product policies. *If you provide Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key with correct value, like for example administrator subscription key, APIM will only execute API policies.*

---

To reduce the frustration it is important to understand policy order execution. Read the whole article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies#configure-scope) but in short the order is:

1. Global scope
2. Product scope
3. API scope
4. Operation scope

---

One last thing, if non subscription product is attached to non subscription API and its policies are executed automatically, you may wonder what happens if we add second open product to the API? Policies from which product will be executed? Turns out, this is not possible (what makes sense). Attempting to add second open product will result in following error:

[image]